# Scikit Learn: RandomForest: clf.predict works with float, but not clf.score

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm working on a classification problem. The labels I am trying to predict:

```
df3['relevance'].unique()
array([ 3.  ,  2.5 ,  2.33,  2.67,  2.  ,  1.  ,  1.67,  1.33,  1.25,
        2.75,  1.75,  1.5 ,  2.25])
```

When I call predict using the features I've made, it works OK:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(df3[features], df['relevance'])
pd.crosstab(clf.predict(df3[features]), df3['relevance'])
```

But when I call clf.score:

```
clf.score(df3['features'], df3['relevance'])
```

I get 
`ValueError`: continuous is not supported

Should I be classifying the relevance label I am trying to predict as another data type? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing happens is likely because your `relevance` column is made up of continuous numbers.

I would suggest switching over to the `RandomForestRegressor()` if you are trying to predict continuous numbers. Otherwise, convert your variables into 1s and 0s based on some threshold value.

Comment: tthanks @ericmjl - the regressor did work. Now to read about it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply encode labels as integers and everything will work well. Floats suggest regression.

In particular you can use LabelEncoder http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

```
>>> from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as RF
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([[0], [1], [1.2]])
>>> y = [0.5, 1.2, -0.1]
>>> clf = RF()
>>> clf.fit(X, y)
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
>>> print clf.score(y, X)
Traceback (most recent call last):
[.....]
ValueError: continuous is not supported
>>> y = [0, 1, 2]
>>> clf.fit(X, y)
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
>>> print clf.score(X, y)
1.0
```

or compute `.score` yourself as this is extremely trivial function

```
print np.mean(clf.predict(X) == y)
```